# How to calculate the sum of duration in a view?

Tags: views, datetime

How to calculate the sum of duration in a view ?
I would like to know the total duration of an album after having entered the duration of each track on the disc.
I use the Duration field and Views Aggregator Plus modules.
The "duration" format is native in excel spreadsheets for example.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you have 2 date fields and you're calculating duration or you're adding/substracting 2 date fields?

Comment: I think they want to sum floating point numbers that represent time durations.

Comment: 57:00 + 3:05 = 1:00:05

Comment: Yes @cilefen, I want to sum time duration (not date) like MM:SS + HH:MM:SS

Comment: I highly doubt you'll find a solution without writing your own custom code. This module stores the duration as a ISO8601 duration string, and as far as I know SQL databases (and therefore views module) don't know how to handle those strings.

Comment: The module also stores durations in seconds (https://git.drupalcode.org/project/duration_field/-/blob/8.x-2.x/src/Plugin/Field/FieldType/DurationField.php#L67), so that field could potentially be summed up instead of the date string.